# How to parse json data in react native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

hi I am new to React native development, how to parse following data please help me

here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/96ebw')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
this.setState({
isLoading: false,
dataSource: responseJson.Pharmacy,
}, 

);
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
});
}

renderItem(dataSource) {
const { List: list } = this.state.dataSource
const { item } = dataSource;

return (
<View style={styles.itemBlock}>
<View style={styles.itemMeta}>
<Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.RxDrugName}</Text>
<Text style={styles.itemLastMessage}>{item.RxNumber}</Text>
</View>

<View style={styles.footerStyle}>
<View style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
<Text style={styles.status}>{ item.StoreNumber }</Text>
</View>

<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
<Image source={require('../assets/right_arrow_blue.png')} />
</View>

</View>
</View>
);
}
```

json is

```
[
  {
    "Pharmacy": {
      "Name": "Hillcrest MOB Pharmacy",
      "StoreNumber": "254",
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "50 Hillcrest Medical Blvd Ste 200-1",
        "City": "WACO",
        "State": "TX",
        "Zip": "76712"
      },
      "IsDefault": false
    },
    "ReadyForPickups": [
      {
        "RxDrugName": "Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
        "RxNumber": "6000295",
        "StoreNumber": "254",
        "PatientPay": "15.59"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "Pharmacy": {
      "Name": "Waco Pharmacy",
      "StoreNumber": "251",
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "1412 N Valley Mills, Suite 116",
        "City": "WACO",
        "State": "TX",
        "Zip": "76710"
      },
      "IsDefault": false
    },
    "ReadyForPickups": [
      {
        "RxDrugName": "Fluoxetine HCL 40mg Caps",
        "RxNumber": "6000233",
        "StoreNumber": "251",
        "PatientPay": "17.3"
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

Comment: You don't need to parse data in react native you can access the object directly like `response[0].Pharmacy.name`

Comment: @rutvik-bhatt if you dont mind can you please add answer with for loop, I didn't get it clearly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the json response is an array of objects. You need to select the object from the array.

For example, if you want the first item in the array you could do the following

`const first = jsonResponse[0]`

```
{
  "Pharmacy":{
    "Name":"Hillcrest MOB Pharmacy",
    "StoreNumber":"254",
    "Address":{
      "StreetAddress":"50 Hillcrest Medical Blvd Ste 200-1",
      "City":"WACO",
      "State":"TX",
      "Zip":"76712"
    },
    "IsDefault":false
  },
  "ReadyForPickups":[
    {
      "RxDrugName":"Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
      "RxNumber":"6000295",
      "StoreNumber":"254",
      "PatientPay":"15.59"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can try using `first.Pharmacy` to capture the data from there.

So `console.log(first.Pharmacy.Name)` should give you Hillcrest MOB Pharmacy

It also looks like you are trying to create and display a list of these Pharmacies. Depending on the number of items you have there are a couple of ways to do that. However, the most performant and easiest is to use a FlatList. This will take care of the view if for any reason that it extends off of the page.

So let's set up the FlatList.

Firstly, import `FlatList` from react-native.

Secondly change the setState call in your componentDidMount to be

```
this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  dataSource: responseJson
}
```

Add the following methods

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
  let { Pharmacy, ReadyForPickups } = item;

  if(!ReadyForPickups[0]) return null;
  let details = ReadyForPickups[0]

  return (
  <View style={styles.itemBlock}>
    <View style={styles.itemMeta}>
      <Text style={styles.itemName}>{details.RxDrugName}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.itemLastMessage}>{details.RxNumber}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
        <Text style={styles.status}>{ details.StoreNumber }</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/right_arrow_blue.png')} />
      </View>

    </View>
  </View>
  );
}

keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
  return index.toString();
}
```

Then your render method should look something like this

```
  render () {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Then it should look something like this. Obviously the stylings are missing and I used a substitute image. But this should be the idea of what you are looking for.

[image]

Hopefully that should be enough to get the data out that you require.

**UPDATE**

Here is a fully working component that renders a list similar to the one above

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// import screens styles
import styles from './styles';

class Pharmacy extends Component {
  /**
   * Construct component class
   * @param {object} props
   */
  constructor (props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        dataSource: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/96ebw')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson
        });
      });
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    let { Pharmacy, ReadyForPickups } = item;

    if (!ReadyForPickups[0]) return null;
    let details = ReadyForPickups[0];

    return (
      <View style={styles.itemBlock}>
        <View style={styles.itemMeta}>
          <Text style={styles.itemName}>{details.RxDrugName}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemLastMessage}>{details.RxNumber}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
          <View style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
            <Text style={styles.status}>{ details.StoreNumber }</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Image source={{uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/949586/pexels-photo-949586.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'}}
              style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
          </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return index.toString();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Pharmacy;
```

**UPDATE 2**

After a chat with the original question poster it seems that they want they only want to show the `ReadyForPickups` items as a single list.

This can be done by performing a map and a reduce on the responseJson so the `setState` call can be updated to the following

```
this.setState({
  isloading: false,
  dataSource: responseJson.map(item => item.ReadyForPickups).reduce((acc, currValue) => { return acc.concat(currValue); }, [])
});
```

This will group the ReadyForPickup items into one long list as follows:

```
[
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
    "RxNumber":"6000295",
    "StoreNumber":"254",
    "PatientPay":"15.59"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Hydroxychloroquine Sulfate 200 Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000339",
    "StoreNumber":"201",
    "PatientPay":"16.18"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Naratriptan HCL 2.5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000300",
    "StoreNumber":"111",
    "PatientPay":"39.04"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
    "RxNumber":"6000457",
    "StoreNumber":"08",
    "PatientPay":"15.59"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Lisinopril 20mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000318",
    "StoreNumber":"08",
    "PatientPay":"13.46"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Fluoxetine HCL 40mg Caps",
    "RxNumber":"6000233",
    "StoreNumber":"251",
    "PatientPay":"17.3"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
    "RxNumber":"6000222",
    "StoreNumber":"232",
    "PatientPay":"15.59"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Memantine HCL 5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000212",
    "StoreNumber":"231",
    "PatientPay":"17.99"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Clonidine HCL 0.1mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000339",
    "StoreNumber":"07",
    "PatientPay":"12.71"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Benazepril HCL 5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000261",
    "StoreNumber":"06",
    "PatientPay":"13.45"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Clonidine HCL 0.1mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000524",
    "StoreNumber":"02",
    "PatientPay":"12.73"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Timolol Maleate 20mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000771",
    "StoreNumber":"02",
    "PatientPay":"15.33"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Benazepril HCL 5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6002370",
    "StoreNumber":"01",
    "PatientPay":"13.45"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Eliquis 5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6002609",
    "StoreNumber":"01",
    "PatientPay":"20.88"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Atorvastatin Calcium 20mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6002602",
    "StoreNumber":"01",
    "PatientPay":"17.69"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName    ":"Astagraf Xl 0.5mg Cp24",
    "RxNumber":"6000232",
    "StoreNumber":"278",
    "PatientPay":"15.33"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Ropinirole HCL 0.5mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000067",
    "StoreNumber":"112",
    "PatientPay":"14.75"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Ciprofloxacin HCL 0.3% Soln",
    "RxNumber":"6000217",
    "StoreNumber":"275",
    "PatientPay":"55.06"
  },
  {
    "RxDrugName":"Sotalol HCL 240mg Tabs",
    "RxNumber":"6000575",
    "StoreNumber":"09",
    "PatientPay":"17.5"
  }
]
```

To match the new dataSource the `renderItem` function should be updated so that it will display the list.

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

  return (
  <View style={styles.itemBlock}>
    <View style={styles.itemMeta}>
      <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.RxDrugName}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.itemLastMessage}>{item.RxNumber}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
        <Text style={styles.status}>{item.StoreNumber }</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/right_arrow_blue.png')} />
      </View>

    </View>
  </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to get all rxdrugnames , can you please help

Comment: @UmaAchanta I have updated my answer to show how to use this data in a FlatList. You will need to be careful when getting RxDrugName as ReadyForPickups is an array of objects and you never know if it might be empty or not.

Comment: @UmaAchanta, everything going ok?

Comment: @UmaAchanta I've just edited my post so that there is a fully working component. You would just need to create a styles file. I changed the image uri as I don't have your image.

Comment: this will give only first item right  'ReadyForPickups[0]'

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is fairly straight forward to make it show all the items. It really just depends on what you want.

Comment: I want to show all the items(ReadyForPickups) . need for loop ,not the first one

Answer (score 1):

Your `responseJson` is array of JSON object with format:

```
{
    "Pharmacy": {
      "Name": "Hillcrest MOB Pharmacy",
      "StoreNumber": "254",
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "50 Hillcrest Medical Blvd Ste 200-1",
        "City": "WACO",
        "State": "TX",
        "Zip": "76712"
      },
      "IsDefault": false
    },
    "ReadyForPickups": [
      {
        "RxDrugName": "Tizanidine HCL 4mg Caps",
        "RxNumber": "6000295",
        "StoreNumber": "254",
        "PatientPay": "15.59"
      }
    ]
}
```

So you should

```
.then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
       isLoading: false,
       dataSource: responseJson
    }
);
```

In  `render()`, you can `map()` each item in `dataSource` and call `renderItem()` as your code:

```
render() {
  return (
     <View>
       {this.state.dataSource.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
     </View>
  )
}
```

And in `renderItem(item)`, `item` now is a JSON object with above format, you can render it easily.

```
renderItem(obj) {

   const item = (obj.ReadyForPickups || [])[0] || {};
   // this will secure your app not crash when item is invalid data.

   return (
     <View style={styles.itemBlock}>
       <View style={styles.itemMeta}>
         <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.RxDrugName}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.itemLastMessage}>{item.RxNumber}</Text>
       </View>

       <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
         <View style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
           <Text style={styles.status}>{ item.StoreNumber }</Text>
         </View>

         <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
           <Image source={require('../assets/right_arrow_blue.png')} />
         </View>

       </View>
   </View>
);
}
```